# Name Server Change From NameCheap to AWS, Giving the message example.com’s server DNS address could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, namecheap

I registered my domain on namecheap.com, and trying to host my profile static site in AWS S3, I'm trying to change the name servers followed the rules given in AWS Amazon Route 53 but not successful, here are the steps i followed.

Created Hosted Zones as below
[image]

and in my namecheap.com i changed the nameserver as below 
[image]

But still I'm getting DNS cannot be resolved when hit my site. and my S3 buckets are configured properly as i can view my site with S3 url, any help is appreciated

I created alias by clicking on the Create Record Set and added the below configuration
[image]

Comment: The name server propagation takes some time give like atleast 12-24 hrs for the propagation.

Comment: Yes, I waited for 24 hours, i did that 2 days ago, Thanks for the comment

Comment: What is the domain?Let me take a look in current name servers.

Comment: the domain name is rajendra.io

Comment: The name servers are propagated. Are you sure that Alias is correct? is the bucket URL working in browser and showing your website?

Comment: The URL for the bucket is www.rajendra.io.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ which is again redirect host to rajendra.io but www.rajendra.io will be appended i guess because s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ is the only option that is showing up in the alias drop down. The orginal bucket will be http://rajendra.io.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ Thanks

Comment: Did you follow the exact steps shown here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

Comment: Yes, Hopefully followed each and every step, that is how i got to this point of changing the name servers, Thanks for your time. Hopefully i will get it resolved.

Comment: One question what is the name of the bucket where your website files are?

Comment: I already mentioned, here is the link you can actually view it http://rajendra.io.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Can you show me screenshot how you are adding a Alias to your domain or write down the steps?

Comment: Hi, edited the question and added the screen shot at the bottom, i created by clicking on create record set and selected alias and when i clicked on alias target that url showed up and i selected as mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Thats the issue :) Do not add www just keep it blank your bucket will show up in the alias.

Comment: Changed it but looks like it is still showing up s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com

Comment: Cool its working thanks a lot!!

Comment: Ok I am creating the answer below. Please mark it correct.

Comment: sure i will upvote it thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117856/discussion-between-error2007s-and-nagarajendra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating a website using S3 always make sure your bucket name matches the name of the the domain.

So for example if you are mapping www.domain.com to S3 then your bucket name should be "www.domain.com" and if you want to map domain.com then your bucket name should be "domain.com" or the bucket endpoint will not show up in the alias like it happened in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i had one more glitch, I'm able to access rajendra.io but not www.rajendra.io any idea?

Comment: You have 2 bucket right? One is rajendra.io and another www.rajendra.io

Comment: yes, and i had the redirection for www.rajendra.io bucket to rajendra.io bucket URL where the code resides!!

Comment: You don't have to redirect www.rajendra.io bucket to rajendra.io bucket change that rule to redirect www.rajendra.io bucket to rajendra.io domain check this screenshot http://imgur.com/gallery/o8Iax